# Plural-ling plurals

Tags: wordplay, language

On one recent car trip my mates and I were discussing the endlessly fascinating world of English Language.
When one of us brought up the famous "*octopus* plural becomes *octopi*" it started a whole gamut of interesting ideas. "solar plexus" became "solar plexi", "campus" became "campi" and "fuss" became "fi". ([see here for more](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58714/when-do-i-use-i-for-expressing-the-plural-of-a-word)
)
We messed around, thinking of many other words that we could apply this rule to.
(One interesting one we came up with - plural of 'bus'? Bi!)

The riddle simply is this: Given that EVERY word in the English language would obey the above rule, what plural of a plural would make it's singular?

Please peek at the following disclaimer/clue ONLY when you've totally given up, downed your last twinkies and about to trash your brothers PS3 out of frustration... ONLY then may you peek..

> This puzzle was very successful when tested out verbally. Seeing it now in the written form, I see how it may be much easier... but hey! that's showbiz.
>  (Post edited question - I don't think this disclaimer applies anymore...)

Comment: For what it’s worth, *-us* pluralized as *-i* is the rule for Latin’s second declension masculine nouns, many of which have found their way into English and are sometimes (though with decreasing frequency) still pluralized in a Latin style. More than one *cactus* becoming *cacti*, for example. However, *octopus* is actually a common mis-attribution of this rule: it comes from Greek, not Latin, and so its plural (in Greek) would be *octopodes*. As with *cactuses*, *octopuses* is also acceptable. *Octopi*, though, is basically nonsense—though nonsense so common that some accept it.

Comment: (You may very well have already known all this—might be what you meant when you called it “famous”—but I was forced through too many years of Latin education to not lecture when it comes up :P)

Comment: @KRyan :-) no worries. it's always great to learn something new. Check out the link in the question - it references your comments...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If we were to pluralize

> "us"

it would become

> "I"

Comment: nice! Just out of interest - did it help that you saw the question visually? do you think it would be more difficult verbally?

Comment: I looked at the hint, which may have helped. Honestly, it was the ' "....us" and seeing what results we get when changed to "....i".' bit that did it

Comment: k.  edited the question to make it not so obvious..